# Configure glow/shrink animation to a text

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to give glow/shrink animation to a text in PowerPoint using VBA.

I can not configure it to give size 110% (it takes default size 150%) & also want a smooth end to 2 sec.

I tried the scale property but did not get my result.

```vb
Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
Set dshp = osld.Shapes("LeftText")

osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect dshp, msoAnimEffectGrowShrink, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious

For C = 1 To osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count
    Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence(C)

        oeff.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
        oeff.Timing.TriggerDelayTime = 2
        'oeff.Behaviors.Add(msoAnimTypeScale).ScaleEffect.ByY = 110
        'oeff.Behaviors.Add(msoAnimTypeScale).ScaleEffect.ByX = 110

Next C
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub GlowAnimationOptions()
    Dim effGrowShrink As Effect
    Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set dshp = osld.Shapes("LeftText")

    Set effGrowShrink = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=dshp, EffectID:=msoAnimEffectGrowShrink, Trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
    
    With effGrowShrink
        With .EffectParameters
            .Size = 120
        End With
        With .Timing
            .SmoothEnd = msoTrue
            .Duration = 4
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sir, I tried your suggestion but still, it shows size 150%(not changes to 120%) & smooth end duration also not working.

Comment: I'm aware that the number _displayed_ in the Effect Options dialog does not change. Please run your animation without the the macro and make a note of the final size. Then apply the macro, run the animation and note the smaller final size at the end.

Comment: Thanks, sir It's perfectly working. It displays 150% in the Effect Options dialog but actually its 120%.